# How to get read lock informations from mongodb using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to get read lock details from mongodb by using nodejs. I have used below code.  But it returns errors like "command not found".

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var output = "";
var Db = require('mongodb').Db, Server = require('mongodb').Server;

var db = new Db('admin', new Server(conf.host, conf.port));

db.open(function(err, db1) {

                    var adminDb = db1.admin();
                    adminDb.authenticate(conf.user, conf.password, function(err, result) {

          if(result == true) {

                db.command({"waitingForLock" : true, $or: [ { "op" : { "$nin" : [ "insert", "update", "remove" ] } },{ "query.findandmodify": { $exists: true } } ]  },function(err,result) {
                                 if (err) { console.log("error="+err); return false; }
                                         output = result;
                                        console.log("mongodb read lock object info"+util.inspect(output, true, 10, true));


                                  });

}

});
});
```

please give any solution.

Comment: You mean [`currentOp`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/currentOp/) which is the actual command associated with the shell helper of the same name. Please note that you need run this from the "admin" database otherwise it will error.

Comment: Yes. I am connecting through Admin database only.

Comment: Any solution please ?

Comment: Seriously? It's right there in the comment.

Comment: Yes. see the code. I have mentioned "admin" database.